# Why, according to the OECD, should inflation decrease in the coming months?

Tags: inflation, forecasting

As you can see in this graph: https://data.oecd.org/price/inflation-forecast.htm according to the OECD, inflation is expected to decrease in the coming months. I would like to know why.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to read their official documentation in the link you provided. That way you hear the explanation of the OECD, as opposed to someone else's opinion /research.

The direct link is [here](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/economics/oecd-economic-outlook/volume-2022/issue-1_62d0ca31-en).

P.35 reads as such:

> Inflation is still projected to moderate next year in most countries,
> provided that the peak in global energy prices is passed, as assumed,
> in early 2023 (Annex 1.A.) and supply-chain constraints wane
> gradually. Moderating demand growth will also help to ease inflation
> pressures. Even so, headline and core inflation are projected to
> remain higher in 2023 than previously foreseen, and in many cases
> above central bank policy objectives (Figure 1.21). With inflation now
> seen as staying higher for longer in most OECD economies, many central
> banks are now expected to raise interest rates more quickly than
> previously assumed...

However, there are many more sections discussing inflation but this summarizes it nicely.